# best way to add column without using ifelse

Tags: r, match

I have a data frame d and I'd like to add a VALUE_GROUP column that looks at the value field and returns the upper limit of the bucket the value falls into

```
Value           Value_group
 0<=value<5        5
 5<=value<10       10
 10<=value<15        15
 15<=value<20        20
```

You can see the Value_group is the max possible value in the bucket i.e. for value between 0 and 5 Value_group = 5

```
d =data.frame(group = rep("A",20),value = seq(1,20,1))
d
d$Value_Group  = ??
```

Value_group can be added using multiple ifelse() statements but is there a better way?

```
The result would be:
       group value   Value_Group
    1      A     1      5
    2      A     2      5
    3      A     3      5
    4      A     4      5
    5      A     5      5
    6      A     6      10
    7      A     7      10
    8      A     8      10
    9      A     9      10
    10     A    10      10 
    11     A    11      15
    12     A    12      15
    13     A    13      15
    14     A    14      15
    15     A    15      15
    16     A    16      20
    17     A    17      20
    18     A    18      20
    19     A    19      20
    20     A    20      20
```

Thank you.

Comment: `d$Value_Group = cut(d$value, seq(0,20,5), labels=seq(5,20,5), right=FALSE, include.lowest=TRUE)`

Comment: usually you would want to use `merge` when you have look-ups like these.

Comment: Are the value intervals always 5? if so you can simply do `d$Value_Group = floor((d$value + 4)/5) * 5`.

Comment: @Psidom, given the category definitions, I think that should be `floor((d$value + 5)/5) * 5`, but you could also do `(d$value %/% 5 + 1) * 5`.

Comment: @eipi10 I think it actually should be `4`, otherwise values like `5`, `10` will be rolled to the next group instead of the current one.

Comment: right = TRUE seems to work d$Value_Group = cut(d$value, seq(0,20,5), labels=seq(5,20,5), right=TRUE, include.lowest=TRUE)

Comment: @Psidom, If you look at the OP's category definitions, he wants 5 in the `10` group, 10 in the `15` group, etc.

Comment: @eipi10 OK. I see what you mean now. I was looking at the result data frame. According to his definition, yes you are right.

Comment: Ah, I see, there's a mismatch between the category definitions and the expected output. Use `right=TRUE` (the default) if going by the expected output. Use `right=FALSE` if going by the category definitions, and *mutatis mutandis* for @Psidom's answer.

Comment: Is the data.frame formatted like the first table i.e. `Value` is a character formated as  `A<=value<B`?